# Converting HTML to proper Excel File

Tags: java, apache-poi

I currently create xls files by outputting an HTML table with the proper header and file extension. Here is the sample code:

```
String tabledata = "<table>MORE TABLE HTML HERE</table>";
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"somefile.xls\""); 
out.println(tabledata);
```

This works great except you get an error before opening "The file format and extension of 'somefile.xls' don't match." Once opened, it looks exactly how I want it.

I used Apache POI elsewhere, so figured I could try using this, but I don't want to have to build all elements in some long script looking for rows, columns and different styles. I was thinking that I could convert the HTML to an InputStream and then create the Workbook, but it doesn't like the headers. Here is the code:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(tabledata.getBytes("UTF-8"));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("somefile.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Is something like this possible if the headers were added/changed? If so, how would I modify this code to work properly?

Comment: Formats are not magically convertible. The fact that opening a file like that in excel works is that excel realizes it's an HTML file and treats it as such. To make a file that is in proper excel format, you have to actually create rows, columns, styles etc.

Comment: I am fine with it still being treated as HTML, but can you get around that error? I assume not since it is probably saying that since you can have injections in the HTML, but was hoping it was going to be easier than analyzing the HTML and building all the individual pieces.

Comment: Sigh. The error is because you told it that an HTML is an XLS. It sees that the file is not an XLS file. It complains, and then tries to get the data from the HTML file. If you want to get rid of the error, you need to give it an XLS file that is in actual XLS format. Or an HTML file that is an actual HTML file.

Comment: For an example of converting HTML to a 'proper' .xlsx file see: https://github.com/alanhay/html-exporter

Comment: @AlanHay is this project still valid? Or are there any other libs in place which can be used? The last update for this lib was approx. 5 years ago